# <a> tag not being echoed from php to html

Tags: php, html, datatable

I'm trying to echo a hiperlink tag from php to html inside a row in a table. However in HTML I try to click on the row and it isn't clickable. Dont know what could I be doing wrong, any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
<table id= "pacientes">
      <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Última actualización</th>
          <th>Telefono</th>
      </tr>
      <?php
          $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
          if ($conn->connect_error) {
              die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
          } 
          $sql = "SELECT ID, Nombre, Telefono, UltAct FROM Paciente WHERE Medico = '$ID'";
          $result = $conn->query($sql);

          if($result-> num_rows > 0){
              while($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
                  echo "<a href=javascript:OcultarTabla(); id=paciente><tr><td>" . $row["ID"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Nombre"] . "</td><td>" . $row["UltAct"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Telefono"] . "</td></tr></a>" ;
              }
              echo "</table>";
          }
          else {
              echo "No hay pacientes registrados";
          }
          $conn->close();
        ?>
```

I know that the id and the href should have double quotations, but if I add them it gives me a syntax error. This way the html page loads up but the row isn't clickable. The javascript function is the following.

```
 function OcultarTabla() {
          if (document.getElementById('paciente').clicked) {
             document.getElementById('pacientes').style.display = 'none';
          }
          else 
             document.getElementById('ifYes3').style.display = 'block';
        }
```

Comment: Invalid HTML, `<a>` is not allowed around `<tr>`/`<td>`. Use a JS click event on the row

Comment: @brombeer can you develop a bit more? I'm just starting on using HTML JS and PHP, thanks!

Comment: Move your links _inside_ the `<td></td>`s for it to be valid and link your `$row["ID"]`, `$row["Nombre"]` etc individually. Or use Javascript to detect a click on the complete table row, I'm sure there are tutorials out there. Or add another column that has the link in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using double quotes " " for href and id use single qoutes ' '

when your using " " to define your string you need to use the single qoutations so you dont break out the string

(believe that's the right terms feel free to correct if not)

so you should have: (I believe I put the quotes in the right place)

```
 echo "<a href='javascript:OcultarTabla();' id='paciente'><tr><td>" . $row["ID"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Nombre"] . "</td><td>" . $row["UltAct"] . "</td><td>" . $row["Telefono"] . "</td></tr></a>" ;
```

Comment: It didn't throw me any syntax errors, but the hyperlink isn't working yet, maybe its due to what @brombeer says, thanks anyways :)

Comment: Yup his comment should fix your issue, I forgot that part of the question sorry